# VB.net object initializer array object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to use object initializer to set up a custom array in vb.net, there may be only 1 entry or there could be 100 on any given instance of this array. I have been successful in completing this task in C# however can not find documentation of completing it in Vb.net

I have a model:

```
Public Class Artist
    Public Name As String
    Public Task As String
End Class
```

within another model we have further listed this object as part of the collection

```
    Public Property Artists() As Artist
```

which brings me to the controller

```
            .Artists = New Artist() With
            {.Name = "bob", .Task = "1"}
```

that is successful for 1 entry; how would I add another entry under the same instance of the object such as the following in c#

```
Artists = new Artist[]
{
    new Artist() { name = "bob", Task = "1" },
    new Artist() { name = "fred", Task = "2" },
    new Artist() { name = "george", Task = "3" }
}
```

this all falls within a with statement itself being a sub of another object which seems to rule out traditional dimensioning

```
    Dim cB = New CB {
        .StoryTitle = "Test"
        .IsbnNumber = 200
        .Artists = new Artists...
}
```

**Ultimate Solution**

```
    Dim cB = New CB With {
        .StoryTitle = "Test",
        .IsbnNumber = 200,
        .Artists = New Artist() {New Artist() With {
    .Name = "bob",
    .Task = "1"
}, New Artist() With {
    .Name = "fred",
    .Task = "2"
}, New Artist() With {
    .Name = "george",
    .Task = "3"
}}
    }
```

Comment: IMHO change the type of `Artists` to `List(Of Artist)` and then you would have the `Add` method to add another instance to that current list/instance. Or a see about initializing a multidimensional [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable#to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-by-using-array-literals)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ sometimes you want to use an Array without the Add method, for example take an API you might not want to expose an object with an `Add` method to the caller.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I know, that was a suggestion, especially if the OP want's to add/remove other entries *later*... Also I linked the docs as the user mentioned they couldn't find the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been successful in completing this task in C# however can not find documentation of completing it in Vb.net

Download [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), drag/drop your Exe or Dll that you successfully created with C# and save project as a VB.Net project.

I'm bilingual with C# and VB.Net but when it comes to Lambda's and LINQ in VB.Net this is how I translate between the languages.

Or an even simpler and quicker method is: http://converter.telerik.com/

C#:

```
Artists a = new Artist[]
{
    new Artist() { name = "bob", Task = "1" },
    new Artist() { name = "fred", Task = "2" },
    new Artist() { name = "george", Task = "3" }
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Dim a As Artists = New Artist() {New Artist() With {
    .name = "bob",
    .Task = "1"
}, New Artist() With {
    .name = "fred",
    .Task = "2"
}, New Artist() With {
    .name = "george",
    .Task = "3"
}}
```

Comment: I have used Telerik but it does not like these defined objects (throws errors)

this falls in a with statement itself which creates an issue using a dimension 

        With cB
            .StoryTitle = "test"
            .IsbnNumber = 200
            .Artists =...

Comment: lack of former data added to the opening post

Comment: Could it be that your C# syntax is incorrect, notice how I declare it with **a**, where as your version wont work in CodeConverter: `Artists = new Artist[]`

Comment: Dim cB = New CB With {
            .SeriesTitle = "Test",
            .IssueNumber = 200,
            .Artists = New Artist() {New Artist() With {
        .Name = "bob",
        .Task = "1"
    }, New Artist() With {
        .Name = "fred",
        .Task = "2"
    }, New Artist() With {
        .Name = "george",
        .Task = "3"
    }}
        }
is ultimately what worked, you got me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little bit off. Try this:

```
    Dim artists() As Artist = {
        New Artist() With {.Name = "bob", .Task = "1"},
        New Artist() With {.Name = "bob", .Task = "1"}
    }
```